# Запуск таймера при нажатии на клавиатуру или при клике

Tags: javascript, jquery

Таймер должен отсчитываться после последнего момента нажатия на клавиатуру или на мышку. Подскажите как сделать это просто и достаточно?

```
var timeoutID1;

//тут должна быть проверка нажата ли клавиша на клаве или на мышке  
if(нажатие){
   //проверка установлен ли таймер, если установлен очистить и запустить 
   if(timeoutID1){
       clearTimeout(timeoutID1);
       timeoutID1 = setTimeout(searchExecutor, 30000);
   }
}
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var timer,
    counterVal = 1;

function counterStart() {
    if (timer) {  // проверка наличия таймера
        clearInterval(timer); // сброс таймера, если он уже работает
        console.log('reset');
    } else {
        console.log('start');
    }
    counterVal = 1;
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        console.log(counterVal++);
    }, 1000);
}

window.addEventListener('click', counterStart);  // слежка за нажатием мышки
window.addEventListener('keypress', counterStart); // слежка за нажатием клавиши
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы на правильном пути, отслеживать нужно события нажатия и клика:

```js
let timer = null, time = 1000;

function end(){
  console.info('Превышен лимит бездействия!');
  document.removeEventListener('keydown', activity);
  document.removeEventListener('click', activity);
}

function activity(){
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(_ => end(), time);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', activity);
document.addEventListener('click', activity);

activity();
```